# compiling issue with netBeans 11.2

Tags: c, netbeans

NetBeans is giving me so much headaches, i need to set it up for my lab class, the issue is if i download and re-install it, it will build for the first time, but then it wont run, then after the first time i built, it wont let me built anymore, ive been doing alot of research, some saying that it could be the MinGW packages, but i downloaded all the basic MinGW packages, seems like the same issue occurs. please help

```
cd 'C:\Netb\Lab_1'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Netb/Lab_1'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/lab_1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Netb/Lab_1'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
gcc     -o dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/lab_1 build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/lab_1.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/lab_1.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Netb/Lab_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Netb/Lab_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

[image]

Comment: the same code works on IDE 8.2 that is installed in my class in school

Comment: ***cannot open output file dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/lab_1.exe: Permission denied*** This is the issue.

Comment: Please don't spam language tags, only tag the language you're actually program in. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it ***as text*** (though the code is not important for this type of error).

Comment: As for "Permission denied" issues, on Windows it could mean one of three things: 1) The program is already running; 2) You don't have write-access to the directory where the executable file is about to be written; Or 3) Your anti-virus is meddling.